# session servlets and href tag

Tags: java, session, servlets, href

what I'm trying to do is relative simple
In my webapp there are these two servlets:
(I will write some pseudocode)

**servlet A code:**  :

```
    HttpSession sess = req.getSession();

    String str = (String) sess.getAttribute("log");

    if(str == null)
    {
     // send html page with a form
     // to enter password and name 
     // data will be proceessed by servlet B
    }
    else
    {
     // send html page with a form
     // to enter only a name 
     //data will be proceessed by servlet B
    }
```

**servlet B code:**  :

```
       HttpSession sess = req.getSession();

       String logged =  (String) sess.getAttribute("log");

       if(logged == null)
       {

        //check if password correct

            if(correct)
            {
             sess.setAttribute("log","ok");

             // print name 
             // and tell the user
             // that next time password
             // will not be requested
            }
            else
            {
             // print error message
            }

       }
       else
       {
       // print name
       }
```

for some reason the second time the servlet A is called after that the user filled in password and name correctly
**str** is **null** so the **if** part gets printed.

EDIT:

I discovered that if the user after inserting the password and 
being redirected to servletB writes the url of servletA by himself
all goes right , but it odesn't work when the user gets back to the previous
page using a link created by servletA:
 A HREF=\"http://localhost:8080/Blog/ServletA\" back

again , any suggestions why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I believe its not entering in your `if(correct)` block i.e. `correct` condition is not getting satisfied. Correct the condition there and make sure, it sets the `log` attribute in the `session`. Once a attribute is set into the session, its there until session expires or your remove it.